# twice differentiable, invariant under rotation?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, rotations

Alexandrov's theorem, defines the notion of twice differentiable(smooth) and
shows that convex functions have this property, almost everywhere.
See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_theorem

Given a convex compact region $R$ in the plane, we can describe its lower and upper envelope by a convex and a concave function.
See the figure, with $f_1$ as lower and $f_2$ as upper envelope.

[image: A convex set with an upper and lower envelope.]

In this way, we can define, 
for each point on the boundary of $R$, 
whether the point is smooth or not.

Now, if $R$ is rotated, we would get 
two potentially different functions.
And potentially, there could be a point that
was declared before as smooth and now 
after the rotation is not anymore.

I don't think this can happen, except for 
some potential special boundary cases.

My question: Is the smoothness of a convex object rotation invariant?

Comment: What do you mean by "lower and upper envelope"? Also note that Alexandrov theorem is about convex functions defined on open sets, i.e., it does not make an assertion about the behavior on the boundary of $R$.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question, by adding a figure. The boundary of C, define the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$, which can live in an open interval, if you want. I know that there are some points, for which we cannot define smoothness in this way, but if smoothness, does not depend on the rotation, than this should be no problem.

Comment: seems as though you'd get non-smoothness at the seams where f1 meets f2 ... as you rotate the piece, those seams become candidates for differentiability

Comment: This is true. But this is not the important issue. Important is only that for any point $p$ on the boundary, it holds that for any rotation, where the point $p$ is not at the seams, it is either always smooth or never smooth.